# NodeJS command to restart calling process

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a command that forces the calling process to restart itself? I have a process querying a database that I would like to start over only if certain events occur.

Comment: I'm sorry. Can you elaborate your issue?

Comment: I assume you mean reset the request and execute the app as if starting anew?

Comment: Why couldn't you just have this process be an exported function that you than call from what ever event is supposed to fire it off? Also as stated above you really need to specify your problem with examples because this could be a subset of  a million other similar sounding issues. Like is this event based in your node code is this a server event.. etc

Comment: @PetarVasilev yes that is exactly what I mean

Comment: @AndrewFont this is in the node.js server code. What I am trying to do will not work as a function, it requires a separate process.

Comment: `process.exit(1)` which you can handle in the parent by listening to `exit` events and re-spawn the child process. You can use something other than `1` to indicate something specific.

Comment: @KevinReilly would you be able to give me an example of this? If I try to respawn the child process by listening to the exit message e.g. `if (message===1) var n = cp.fork('the_childprocess.js')` then it only exists in the scope of the `if` statement and none of my other handlers apply anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the supervisor module for nodejs which will continuously monitor your app.
You can install it by using the below command:

```
sudo npm install supervisor -g
```

After this from command line just say

```
sudo supervisor app.js
```

Now your app will be monitored and as soon the as the app exits it will again be restarted a fresh. Supervisor also monitors your full folder structure and whenever a file is changed it will again restart the app.

For exiting your script you can use `process.exit();` as required...